# Appending access code input into URL as utm tag

Tags: html, utm

I'm currently building a landing page with an access code form field.
I'm stuck on finding a way to get the access code entered into a form to be appended as a tag on the url.

Enter "12345" into field and on submit direct to url "www.website.com/?code=12345"

Below is the code I have so far - :

```js
<script>
function btntest_onclick(){
    if (document.getElementById('input-code').value == '1234','5678','9809') {
        var domain = "http://www.website.com?";
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        window.location.href = url
    } 
    else {
        alert ( 'not found' );
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<center>
<span class="text-container">
<input type="text" name="accesscode" placeholder="ACCESS CODE" maxlength="10" size="25" id="input-code">
<p><a href="#" class="btn" onclick="return btntest_onclick()">ENTER</a></p>
</span>
</center>
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you are trying to do in your code. Can the access code be whatever and that will be appended to the URL or will the access code has to match with a predefined list of access codes before making the redirect?

Comment: Yes apologies - the access code will be predefined (approx 15 different codes) and would like the ability to append any of these codes to the url redirect as utm tags when submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems in the code:

- The `if` containing `document.getElementById('input-code').value == '1234','5678','9809'`. That's not a valid conditional statement in JS. I assume you were trying to test if the value was equal to any of the strings, which can be done using `||` (A logical "or").
- The code was never added to the end of the URL.
- You never defined the `url` variable you were redirecting to.

Here's a commented version that should explain some ways to do this:

```js
function btntest_onclick() {
  // First, we assign the value to a variable, just to keep the code tidy
  var value = document.getElementById('input-code').value
  // Now we compare that variable against each valid option
  // if any of these are true, we will progress
  if (value === '1234' || value === '5678' || value === '9809') {
    // Use a template literal (The ` quotes) to build the new URL
    var url = `http://www.website.com?code=${value}`
    // This could also be written as:
    // var url = "http://www.website.com?code=" + value
    // Navigate to your new URL (Replaced with an alert as a demonstration):
    alert(url)
    // window.location.href = url
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show the alert
    alert('not found')
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <span class="text-container">
<input type="text" name="accesscode" placeholder="ACCESS CODE" maxlength="10" size="25" id="input-code">
<p><a href="#" class="btn" onclick="return btntest_onclick()">ENTER</a></p>
</span>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks for the commented version @DBS - this helps a lot. I've just given it a go however, the value is still not appending to the end of the url.

Comment: @crspy Hmm, that's odd. The only situation I can think of where this might not work is when you try to add query parameters to the page you are currently on. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yep on the money there. It worked when I changed the URL to redirect somewhere else and if I use a subdomain. Thanks for your help!